# How to create a countdown timer that countdown html text 60 to 0

Tags: javascript, html

Im working on a larger project but I'm trying out a simpler version of countdown timer with only seconds and not minutes. Code below description

So basically I have 60 seconds in html(id="initial"). I have button with a function called timer.
In javascript i get the value in the h3 tag, by using parseint on the variable and of course innerHTML to get the text inside the tag itself.

Then I create a new variable called newTime and basically set it to newTime = initial--;
Then I update the initial with innerHTMl, like initial.inneHTML = newTime.
It doesnt work, however. Anyways heres the code:

```js
setInterval(setUp, 1000);

function setUp(){

    var initial = parseInt(document.getElementById("initial").innerHTML);
    
    var newTime = initial--;
    
    initial.innerHTML = newTime;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setUp()">Activate timer</button>
<h3 id="initial">60</h3>
```

Comment: Besides the button click calling the wrong code, the main problem is this line: `initial.innerHTML = newTime;` while you can in theory refer to the `<h3>` using its id like that, you are declaring `initial` as variable inside the function and assigning a number to it. In other words, there is no `initial.innerHTML`.  Here's your code fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/4wnxbLhf/

Comment: If somebody answers your question please consider [upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and/or [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are firing setUp function, not the Interval itself. Assign the interval to a variable and pass that to onclick.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. the interval handling, but that's covered in another post
2. The variable `initial` is assigned integer and then treated as if it was an element.

**A solution for problem 2:**

```
var initialElement = parseInt(document.getElementById("initial").innerHTML);
function setUp(){

    var initialValue = parseInt(initialElement.innerHTML);
    
    var newTime = initialValue--;
    
    initialElement.innerHTML = newTime;
}
```

I really do recommend looking up the element just once, instead of once per interval

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the `innerHTML` of an integer.

```js
var initial = document.getElementById("initial");
var newTime = parseInt(initial.innerHTML)-1;
initial.innerHTML = newTime;
```

Also, you should run `setInterval(setUp, 1000);` on click and save the result:

```html
<button onclick="myTimer=setInterval(setUp, 1000);">Activate timer</button>
```

You need a way to stop the timer as well:

```js
if (newTime == 0)
    clearTimeout(myTimer);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues, I'll try to address them one by one.

1. Currently, the `setInterval(setUp, 1000);` is called **before** the button, so the timer would start instant, lets move that inside the function. We'll pass an [anonymous function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp) to the `setInterval` with our code to count down
2. You're saving the `.innerHTML` to the variable `initial`, however, you're trying to use the same variable to set the `.innerHTML` again. Let's separate those into 2 variables, the `element` and the current `value` in each iteration. The `element` can be placed outside the `setInterval` since the reference to the `<h3>` won't change, there's no need to keep calling `getElementById`
3. `value--;` doesn't return anything, it increments the current variable itself, lets remove the extra variable
4. We're not stopping the `setInterval` when we reach `0`, let's fix that too.

Then, we end up with something like this:

```js
function setUp(){
  
    // Save the h3 element
    var element = document.getElementById("initial");

    // Create setInterval, save to variable to clear later
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
         
        // Current element value
        var value = element.innerHTML;
        
        // Decrease
        value--;
        
        // Set value
        element.innerHTML = value;
        
        // Clear if we're at 0
        if (value === 0) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setUp()">Activate timer</button>
<h3 id="initial">60</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the javascript code:

```
function setUp(){

    var initial = parseInt(document.getElementById("initial").innerHTML);
    
    var newTime = initial--;
    
    initial.innerHTML = newTime;
}

function trigger(){
    setInterval(setUp, 1000);
}
```

And on your html:

```
<button onclick="trigger()">Activate timer</button>
<h3 id="initial">60</h3>
```

The idea is to make the button only trigger the interval creation, and making setUp execute each second.

Answer (score 0):

The count down is best done with a `setInterval` call that is stopped by a `clearInterval` call:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick=()=>{
 const inp=document.querySelector('input')
 let n=inp.value-1;
 const handle=setInterval(function(){
   inp.value=n;
   if (!n--) clearInterval(handle);
 },1000)
}
```

```html
<button>start</button>
<input value="10">
```